# Integration of Angular2, TypeScript, npm, gulp

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2015, npm

I'm newer in fronted development.  I'm trying to develop an application using Angularjs2 with TypeScript using Visual Studio 2015. I followed this Quickstart https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/visual-studio-2015.html. But, some doubts have come to my mind. When I install NPM, one folder called "node_modules" is created. Well, after I developed one mini app, I wanted publish it on local IIS. My question is, it's neccesary publish all node_modules folder? Or, can I use some tools, for example Gulp and only publish requiered files?

Answer (score 1):

You will probably want to find some kind of starter project such as [the Webpack seed](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter) or [angular-cli](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli) (I'm sure there are many others).  These projects will create build processes (webpack in both these cases) that generate a distribution bundle.  This distribution bundle is all you will need to publish to IIS.

Also, the entire Javascript suite of build tools and processes is too much to answer in a SO post but node_modules typically contains both dependencies that are used in your final application (such as the Angular2 core code) as well as dependencies that are used to build/test your application (such as grunt/gulp/webpack/karma/etc.).

Comment: Thank you Pace! I will follow your suggestion, I'll check WebPack.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yes, that is correct.  Sorry, I had already migrated myself and forgotten.